# Motherboard changed linux not booting

Tags: linux, boot

[image: motherboard]i had to change my mobo recently. I was running fc9, but after changing mobo fedora is not booting. But i have run fc38, recovered /home folder. Everything is intact in the drive even the windows folder. Attaching image.i need to restart the linux since it also run webmin which i can't recover. Please help. [image: output][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAbH2.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAbH2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

FC9 is from early 2008. There's very little chance it still supports your motherboard. The error messages you show seem to indicate that old linux isn't even able to find all drives.

So, you simply cannot boot FC9 anymore. That's not that tragic, to be honest:
Set up Fedora 38 on a clean medium (SSDs are reasonably cheap these days).

Simplest solution might be to just make an image of your 2008 hard drive (which is probably very small by modern standards), for example into a QCOW2 container, and try to boot that in a VM. On modern CPUs, the performance downsides of that are very slim.

You could also copy the relevant files over to a podman-running container, but I'm afraid FC9 is so old that nobody has a working container image for you.

**Generally:** You wanting to save your webmin stuff probably means this would be a good time to think about technical debt, and start upgrading the underpinnings of whatever you're administrating using webmin.

Comment: I do some  stuffs in linux. Mobo is also old don't worry. If you need mobo configuration I can share. Please help if you know how to recurve.

Comment: I assure you, that's what's wrong here: your FC9 boot process doesn't see the drives you connected. That's with 99% probability due to lack of drivers. My answer addresses how to solve this.

Comment: You said the "new" motherboard is also old. But is it **old enough**? *Did that hardware model exist* when the kernel version that is currently in use in the old FC9 installation was released? If the "new" hardware is newer than about July 2009 (the end-of-support date of FC9) and the kernel has not been updated since then, your hardware may well be too new for that kernel.

Comment: The main question is why is logvol not found since my filesystems are intact. This problem needs solution,can happen to anyone. I was using the same setup till 2019 before lockdown. My mobo crashed and I had to wait for all covid... to get over. Attached current mobo bios for your perusal bro.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eRxs.jpg I don't know what to make of that photo, and I don't see how the problem "I'm jumping hardware with an operating system that is 14 years after its end of life" can happen to anyone

Comment: Well. Can yu tell me how to mkinitrd under linux rescue.?

Comment: Please don't ask completely new questions in the comments

Comment: I believe old initrd is not matching with this mobo drivers . That's why needed help to rebuild the initrd and run the system. Need your help in doing that bro. Regards

Comment: so, please ask a new, detailed question where you describe exactly what you want to do, and where you need help. I can't answer questions asked in the comments to a different question.